# htaccess URL Rewrite almost working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

here's my problem:

I'm working on a Silex project and can't get an issue with the .htaccess resolved.

---

**My folder structure:**

```
incidents_root/
|
|- app/
|- src/
|- vendor/
|- web/
   |
   |- index.php
   |- .htaccess
```

---

**Contents of my `.htaccess` file:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews

    RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteBase /incidents_root/web/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

---

**Defined routes:**

```
$app->get('/', 'register.controller:registerAction')
    ->bind('register');

$app->get('/register', 'register.controller:registerAction')
    ->bind('registerFull');

$app->get('/update', 'update.controller:updateAction')
    ->bind('update');
```

---

When I'm on my local Apache, accessing the project via `http://127.0.0.1/incidents_root/web/` works absolutely fine, all three routes are working perfectly.

But when I upload it to a server, only the `/` route works. Doesn't work if there's anything after the slash. I access it on the server by `http://hostname.com/incidents_test/new_test/web`. And I did change the `RewriteBase`to `/incidents_test/new_test/web/`.

I've already did the following:

- Checked if .htaccess is loaded - it is
- Tried different variations of .htaccess for Silex I found on Google - nothing has changed
- Tried writing the rewrite rules myself to no avail. I usually manage this by myself.

It could be a server configuration issue, but I'm not really sure what to check for. I will gladly provide any information you need if this is not enough.

Comment: `/incidents_test/new/test/web/` OR `/incidents_test/new_test/web`? you have a mismatch between folder and rewritebase in your example

Comment: Sorry, I've corrected that in the question. It actually is `new_test` in both cases.